# Dot message on a Star Wars frisbee team

Tags: cipher

[image]

So I was given this image to "decrypt"/ figure out the message and report back. However I am completely lost... Can anyone give me an idea of where to start? Can anyone solve this? Thanks for whatever information you can give me!

Note: Star Wars oriented frisbee team.

Comment: It's [Morse code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code).

Comment: The problem is its really hard to read

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil If you don't give up, it won't let you down.  Don't tell me you are too blind to see the dots and dashes.

Comment: @Yakk: Perhaps the puzzle should have been given in Braille instead!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit +1

Answer (score 39):

The dots and dashes are [Morse Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code) as noticed by @Randal'thor

When it is translated to text it reads as follows:

> We've known each other for so long, your heart's been aching
> We both know you're too shy to say it
> Inside we both know what's been going on
> We know the game and we're gonna play it
> And if you ask me how I'm feeling
> Don't tell me you're too blind to see
> Never gonna give you up
> Never gonna let you down
> Never gonna run around and desert you
> Never gonna make you cry
> Never gonna say goodbye
> Never gonna tell a lie and hurt you

These are

> the lyrics to '[**Never give you up**](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/rickastley/nevergonnagiveyouup.html)' by Rick Astley, it's a rickroll

As a bonus

**'Fall MMXVI'**

is Roman numerals for

> Fall 2016 (Autumn 2016)

which was the season and year when the puzzle was posted...

Comment: Persistance rulez!

Comment: ...I'm not sure whether to believe this is really what it says or if I should check.

Answer (score 23):

The translation I've got so far is

> WE'VEKNOWNEACHOTHERFORSOLONGYOURHEART'SBSIDEACHINGGBUTYOU'RETOOSHY

Which means you've

> Rickrolled us.

You monster.

Answer (score 1):

Simple Morse code. Just substitute the symbols with letters. Use Wikipedia.
`.----.` means `'` etc. Here is the decrypted version:-

> we have known each other for so long your heart's been aching but you are too shy to say it inside we both know what's been going on we know the game and we're gonna play it and if you ask me how i'm feeling don't tell me you're too blind to see never gonna give you up never gonna let you down never gonna run around and desert you  never gonna say goodbye never gonna tell a lie and hurt you